# Is it possible to access Context, Application, Activity anywhere statically?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, reflection, android-application-class

So the question is, is it really possible to access `Context`, `Application` and specially `Activity` anywhere. Like as in other static class methods without passing parameters?

Eg:

```
public static class YOUR_CLASS{

    public static void YOUR_FUNCTION(){
        Application app = /* GET APPLICATION */;
        Activity act = /* GET ACTIVITY */;
        Context c = /* GET CONTEXT */;

        // USE THEM
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that even possible? If you run a plain old java `main`, what's the current `Activity` supposed to be?

Comment: There's another thing called ANDROID JAVA CONSOLE apart than JAVA CONSOLE. the ANDROID JAVA CONSOLE is able to access ANDROID api because it runs in Android. An example is AIDE ;-)

Comment: Further than that. It's just an example of static not really a console program

Comment: **what's the current ```Activity``` supposed to be?** In AIDE it's the console activity which shows result. And as am telling again, it's just an example

Comment: Edit: hope it doesn't confuses u no more ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible like this:

```
public static void YOUR_FUNCTION(){
    Application app = getApplication();
    Activity act = getActivity();
    Context c = /* app or act, both are Contexts so u can use them as needed */;

    // USE THEM
}

public static Activity getActivity() {
    try{
        Class activityThreadClass = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread");
        Object activityThread = activityThreadClass.getMethod("currentActivityThread").invoke(null);
        Field activitiesField = activityThreadClass.getDeclaredField("mActivities");
        activitiesField.setAccessible(true);

        Map<Object, Object> activities = (Map<Object, Object>) activitiesField.get(activityThread);

        for (Object activityRecord : activities.values()) {
            try
            {
                Class activityRecordClass = activityRecord.getClass();
                Field pausedField = activityRecordClass.getDeclaredField("paused");
                pausedField.setAccessible(true);

                boolean paused=pausedField.getBoolean(activityRecord);

                Field activityField = activityRecordClass.getDeclaredField("activity");
                activityField.setAccessible(true);
                Activity activity = (Activity) activityField.get(activityRecord);

                if(!paused){
                    return activity;
                }
            }
            catch (Throwable e)
            {}
        }
    }catch (Throwable e)
    {}
    return null;
}

public static Application getApplicationContext(){
    try
    {
        Application i=(Application)Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread")
            .getMethod("currentApplication").invoke(null, null);
            
        if(i==null){
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        return i;
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        try
        {
            Application i=(Application)Class.forName("android.app.AppGlobals")
                .getMethod("getInitialApplication").invoke(null, null);
            if(i==null){
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
            return i;
        }
        catch (Throwable e2)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```